# Im trying to create some plant objects to display on my test class in Java but the first part of the result is displaying all 3 variables I put

Tags: java

So I'm new to java and was trying to create an object in my test class using certain variables I give it. Here is the plant code I did so far.

```java
public class Plant{
    private String name;
    private int height; // current height
    private boolean edible; // is it edible or not 

    public Plant(){
        name =  "No Name Plant";
        height = '0';
        edible = false;       
    }

    public Plant(String newName){
        name = newName;
        height = '0';
        edible = false;
    }

    public Plant(String newName, int newHeight, boolean newEdible){
        name = newName;
        height = newHeight;
        edible = newEdible;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public boolean getEdible(){
        return edible;   
    }

    // public int getHeight(){
    // return height;
    // }

    // public boolean getEdible(){
    // return edible;
    // }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height){
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setEdible(boolean edible){
        this.edible = edible;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
         return   name + ". Height is " + height + ". Is it edible? " + edible ;
    }
}
```

And here is the test class I set up to create 3 objects.

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plant rose = new Plant("Rose" + 5 + false);
        Plant orchids = new Plant("Orchids" + 4 + false);
        Plant carrot = new Plant("Carrot" + 5 + true);
        
        System.out.println(rose);
        System.out.println(orchids);
        System.out.println(carrot);
    }
}
```

The second and third part come out fine but the first part doesn't come out the way I want it to, it shows all 3 variables at once instead of just the first one.

Comment: Please note that new users should take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). You get a bronze badge after you do those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method `main()` of class `TestClass`, where you call the constructor for class `Plant`, replace the `+` with a comma, i.e.

```java
Plant rose = new Plant("Rose" , 5 , false);
Plant orchids = new Plant("Orchids" , 4 , false);
Plant carrot = new Plant("Carrot" , 5 , true);
```

The `+` is the string concatenation operator and comma is used to separate arguments when calling a constructor (or any kind of method).

Also note that if you remove the first two constructors in class `Plant` then class `TestClass` will not compile.